# Deploying in GCE through jenkins creates 20 octet-stream files, every time

Tags: deployment, jenkins, google-compute-engine

I have just gotten my jenkins VM working in GCE so that i can deploy through an URL and it's working nicely.

However, every time i deploy something 20 files issaved in my bucket, all named some gibberish with the type application/octet-stream:

```
009d705c4df3f1dad977db3848777703330f221b    641.43 KB   application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
0f29dadc1db1c1e3bd68b5e87c87030b28ff737e    51 B        application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
12179b7c0898cca08d1f2724b0e789ae77b539f4    3.55 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
14876ba2bedf347151e0268c8dde15e71c88b388    6.12 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
3a4948f3c6b79bf9240222609241f881c408d04d    1.63 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
3bc3db8eb76aaced6191a7dcf812796a6fa5057a    2.5 KB      application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
6b4646e0ae099703f738053bfaeeede3a1f8a67e    46.1 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
6d77bca129e58bbf053bbabc86c23b9103bdea0d    194 B       application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
8059e3541a420a5a2f60d99c46d8cc4a5bba3b8f    48.14 KB    application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
92b798df48237e525d34018efdb7f2aace4fdbb4    523.43 KB   application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
b1f22e54252cdb6a84e92414709340d668c33d3a    1,022 B     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
bad8545d6a001b02f6225c2aade36b2100581d0d    2.83 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
bd80270cee4f7e90baed299f1d6ae1be55e7b4a5    10.45 KB    application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
c626a57d3f004800b634679fa1963d7c09ae585b    2.19 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
ce093c434a0f35df34034e6fc58d1889364cfdc2    1.66 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
d7a8d655f068e92a18971d74b410963e35251c8a    422 B       application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
d8dfb95d6e41de19f4112d99d1485a628096848d    185 B       application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
e06cd18064609994d27a83438b0e3dcbfebc5c67    1.39 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
f20ec52431df2c411bcb60965b3a2c212405f747    7.72 KB     application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
fb51d1d331190dfc3f2b6756bea79ff3ff92755d    815 B       application/octet-stream    6 minutes ago
```

Anyone know what's causing this in jenkins?

I opened one of the files and there was some text about linotype and verisign?

Answer (score 0):

When Jenkins runs build, test and deploy steps for your application, it uploads the logs and any build artifacts to Google Cloud Storage where you can view them, as mentioned in this Help Center article [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/push-to-deploy#view_build_logs_and_artifacts).

Comment: @MGJ you can remove Jenkins access to write to Google Cloud Logging which is not recommended, by logging into the Jenkins user interface and removing the following scope from the credentials: http://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write